# Is there any powershell command or argument to bypass UAC

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-remoting, oracle19c

I create a PowerShell script. In that, I extract the oracle DB 19c zip file and install it using response file. The issue was I have to run this PowerShell script using run as admin. Is there any command or argument to bypass the UAC option and select by default yes in the UAC panel?

Powershell script code:

```
$oracleHomePath = "C:\Oracle\db19c"
$responseFilePath = "C:\response_file\db_install.rsp"
Expand-Archive $dbZipFilePath -DestinationPath $oracleHomePath C:\Oracle\db19c\setup.exe -silent -responseFile $responseFilePath
```

Comment: No, because that's the whole point of UAC. There are ways of running the script though such as a scheduled task using a system/administrator account

Comment: See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works) about how UAC process works.